# Sitecore: Render item for which the user does not have read access

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have an item which requires authentication: I have set Extranet\anonymous read access denied. When an anonymous user tries to access that url is redirected to the login page. So good, so far... now we want to allow anonymous users to be able to access when given a "token" in the url. I have set the context item "manually" after the Itemresolver in the httprequestbegin pipeline, setting the httprequestargs property PermissionDenied to false, but it still redirects the user to the login page. Any Idea? I'm trying to avoid putting logic at sublayout level, but at the same time this is (in theory) a one off requirement, so I don't want to overcomplicate it. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security check and redirection to login page is also performed in *Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderLayout.SecurityCheck* processor in *renderLayout* pipeline. There is check in code if current user has read permissions:

```
Context.Item.Access.CanRead()
```

You should override this processor to have ability to show this item.